# I am not able to submit because read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input and a button and it seems that it cannot detect the value of the input. I didn't use any form tag and I am wondering if that is the cause. What am I missing here? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated.

```
<div className="input-group mb-3">  
    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="add a post"/>
        <div class="input-group-append">
              <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => {
              makePost(e.target[0].value, item._id)}} type="button">Post</button>
         </div>                    
</div>
```

Comment: This is an unusual way to control a form in React, you would normally save each input's value into the state, then trigger a function with your button. Are you sure you need to be checking elements values directly? ([Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) regarding React forms)

Comment: Do you need input value on submit?

Comment: I think that ``e.target[0]`` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `e.target` gives you the reference for the button, and no data of the form can be found there.
2. You have duplicate type property `type="submit"` and `type="button"`, type=submit will submit the form, and type=button is just a button.

If you don't want to use React's state, which you probably should anyway. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html, you can wrap your input elements in a `form` element and attach an `onSubmit` handler for the form. Change the button's type to `submit` (remember to add `preventDefault()`, so it won't "POST" the form automatically).

Then in your `e.currentTarget` you will have access to all the elements inside the form.

```js
const Test = () => {
  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    for (let [name, value] of formData.entries()) {
      /* makePost function here or something */
      console.log(name + ":" + value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
    <div className="input-group mb-3">  
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name={"id_maybe"} placeholder="add a post"/>
        <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
         </div>                    
    </div>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this is what](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqgjuv) you're looking for

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const onSubmit = () => {
    posts.push(value);
    setPosts([...posts]);
    setValue("");
  };

  const handleInput = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="input-group mb-3">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="add a post"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={onSubmit}>
          Add Post
        </button>
      </div>

      {posts.map(post => (
        <div>{post}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`e.target[0].value` doesn't work. You cannot find the `0`th element of `e.target`. Instead of doing that, you could try directly accesing `value` using `e.target.value` instead.</strike>

I don't think you're doing it the right way. With all due respect, your code is pretty sloppy. First of all, you have no `<form>` element. Second, you're doing this in a pretty weird way. Instead of using a separate function, you directly insert an arrow function into `button`.

You should also use [State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and add this in your constructor:

```
this.state = {
  items: [],
  text: ""
}
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

First of all, add an `handleChange` button here:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
}
```

You can use something like this for your submit function:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newItem = {
    text: this.state.text,
    id: performance.now()
  };
  this.setState(state => ({
    items: state.items.concat(newItem),,
    text: ""
  }));
}
```

Change this in your render function:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange= {this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} placeholder="add a post"/>
        <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Post</button>
         </div>
</form>
```

You seem to be a newcomer to React, so why don't you read [the React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)?