# How can I get the value of an input from a button click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to concat the value that's on a text input onto a property in the state, but I don't know how to get access to that input's value from the click event.

This is the code i'm working with right now.

```
  onCreateClick = () => {
    const valueFromInput = 

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      stateProperty: prevState.stateProperty.concat(`${valueFromInput}`)
    })
  }
```

Comment: can you show more of t he code please

Comment: yeah whats the react code look like where you have the text input

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65026021/6516699)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it, I have used functional component and hooks instead of class-based component, but I hope you get the logic behind implementation:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [stateProperty, setStateProperty] = useState("");
  const [valueFromInput, setValueFromInput] = useState("");

  const onCreateClick = () => {
    let newString = stateProperty;
    setStateProperty(newString.concat(valueFromInput));
    setValueFromInput("");
    console.log(valueFromInput);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {stateProperty ? stateProperty : "Type Something"}
      <input
        value={valueFromInput}
        onChange={(e) => setValueFromInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={onCreateClick}>append</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-engelbart-1hr8w?file=/src/App.js:0-677)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a reference on the JSX element whose value you want to obtain. Then you can just reference the DOM Element at your event handler. Once you have a reference to that DOM Element, you can just grab the value of the input with `yourElement.value` like a normal HTML element.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

*Copied from the React docs*

**functional component with Hooks**

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  const textInput = useRef(null);
  
  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**class component implementation**

````
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textInput} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````